# Laravel 4 file upload

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to upload some photos and handle this with the build in Laravel functions. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this properly. I have been able to actually upload something, but I've run into a few problems. This is the code I have right now:

If looked at the documentation, and found this function: `$file = Input::file('photo');` I've used this function, and what the content of `$file` becomes is an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`, which, as the documentation tells us, "extends the PHP SplFileInfo class and provides a variety of methods for interacting with the file." http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files

Then I used this function `Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath);` which should but the file in the desired folder on the server. And it did. But now comes the problem. Now all uploaded files have a filename like `phpgoJnLc`, and without an extension.

I've looked at the functions available from `SplFileInfo` and tried `getExtension` which give me an empty string and `getFilename` which also gives me something like `phpgoJnLc`.

Then I looked around on the internet and found a few part of code from Laravel 3, where they did something like this:

`$filename = Str::random(20) .'.'. File::extension(Input::file('photo.name'));`

But the result of this is give me only the result from `Str::random(20)` followed by a dot. Again, no file extension.

So, what am I doing wrong? How to upload a file with Laravel 4?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looking in that same class file I see a `getClientOriginalName()` function...

```
$file = Input::file('photo');
$file->move($destinationPath,$file->getClientOriginalName());
```

... which ais ssuming you *want* to keep the original name your client sets... which could be hazardous, do some safety checks on it would be my advice. Getting the extensionname only is done with `->getClientOriginalExtension()`, so you could also only save that part & add a random string before that in the second argument of the `move()` function.

Comment: You, my friend, just saved my day! How did I not see that...? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, especially when you want to change the name of the uploaded image:

```
$filename = 'New_Name'.'.'.Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also generate a name for the file with the original file extension like so:

```
$filename = Str::random(20) . '.' . Input::file('image')->guessExtension();
```

if you try to use the following in Laravel 4:

```
$filename = Str::random(20) .'.'. File::extension(Input::file('photo.name'));
```

you will get this error:

```
'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::guessExtension()'
```